# Book for a comprehensive (re-)introduction to physics in a single volume

Tags: resource-recommendations, education

Although I hold a masters degree in math, I always struggled with physics, and I was relieved when I didn't have to study it any more. Now that I have been away from the academic scene for more than 25 years, I think I should give physics another go.

I am looking for a single comprehensive volume that will teach me all the basics of physics to a senior college or undergrad level. A single volume because I don't really want to invest the time and money on 12 different books - each focusing on one area.

The book should be highly motivated. In my school and college days, physics was presented to us as a series of equations with no motivation or historical development whatsoever. I don't think I can bear any more of that.

The book has to start from the ground up, without assuming any prior knowledge. It must also suitable for a casual but science-educated reader.

Feynman's lectures could be an obvious choice, but I think they are idiosyncratic and lack examples.

Another option might be the book by [Joos and Freeman](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0486652270). It's cheap but as with all Dover books, it's ancient and I'm not sure how motivated it is.

A more modern option may be [Serway and Jewett](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1305401964), which seems to tick all the boxes.

Comment: PBH, when you read through the physics book, concentrate on identifying and memorizing the underlying concepts of each problem that you work.  In physics, the concepts drive the math, meaning that physics is not purely "a math thing".

Answer (score 2):

I always feel that books like the Feynman lectures in Physics and Landau & Lifshitz are only really worth reading *after* you have an understanding of the subject. That is, you should already be able to do the maths a bit, so that you can better appreciate the physical interpretations.

If you want a single volume but you have time in your hands (for a *long* single volume), I would recommend [University Physics by Young and Freedman](https://www.pearson.com/us/higher-education/program/Young-University-Physics-with-Modern-Physics-Plus-Mastering-Physics-with-e-Text-Access-Card-Package-14th-Edition/PGM76533.html), which covers the basic syllabus of the first year (and half) of an undergraduate physics degree. It's very pedagogical, with tons of worked examples, meant for a first-time *learner*, as opposed to someone with a background already looking to deepen, strengthen, and expand their knowledge.